# Continuity of probability measure proof

Tags: probability

I was wondering if my proof the following claim is valid since it doesn't use the standard "create disjoint subsets" trick

Claim: Suppose $A_n \nearrow A$, i.e. $$A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \dots\ \text{and}\ \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i =: A$$ exists. Then $$\mathbb{P}(A_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(A).$$

Proof: For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have by proper set inclusion that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}A_i = A_n.$$ Hence $A = A_n \cup (A \setminus A_n)$ so \begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(A) & = \mathbb{P}(A_n) + \mathbb{P}(A \setminus A_n) - \mathbb{P}(A_n \cap (A \setminus A_n)) \\
& = \mathbb{P}(A_n) + \mathbb{P}(A \setminus A_n)
\end{align*} since $A_n \cap (A \setminus A_n) = \emptyset.$ Thus we have the formula $$\mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \mathbb{P}(A \setminus A_n).$$ We assert that $\mathbb{P}(A \setminus A_n) \rightarrow 0.$ But note that $$A \setminus A_n = \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right) \setminus \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i\right) \Longrightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A \setminus A_n = A \setminus A =  
\emptyset.$$ Hence $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(A \setminus A_n) = 0$$ so we conclude that $\mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A_n) \rightarrow 0$, i.e. $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n) = \mathbb{P}(A).$$

Comment: The key is when you say $$\lim_n \mathbb{P} (A \setminus A_n) = \mathbb{P} (\lim_n A \setminus A_n) = \mathbb{P} (A \setminus A)$$ If this was previously proved, then your proof is ok.

Comment: @Crostul I have not formally proved this, but I believe I can show this by saying since $A \setminus A_{n+1} \subset A \setminus A_n$ for all $n$, then $$\mathbb{P}(A\setminus A_{n+1}) \leq \mathbb{P}(A\setminus A_n)$$ so $\mathbb{P}(A\setminus A_n)$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence of real numbers bounded from below by its infimum $0$ so it must converge to it.

Comment: It's bounded below by 0, but that only tells you that $\lim_n\Bbb P(A\setminus A_n)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(A-A_n)=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}(A-A_n)= \emptyset$

You use that $P(A-A_n) \to P(\emptyset)=0$ which is exactly what you want to prove namely the continuity of this measure.

This is a valid proof if you want to keep in mind:

> $A=A_1 \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_{n+1}-A_{n})$ which is a disjoint union.
>
> Now $$P(A)=P(A_1)+\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^nP(A_{n+1}-A_n)=P(A_1)+ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(P(A_{i+1})-P(A_i))$$ $$=P(A_1)+\lim_{ n \to \infty}P(A_{n+1})-P(A_1)=\lim_{n\to \infty}P(A_{n+1})$$ and we are done.